# Get all 'li' images inside Flexbox 'ul' container to same, fixed size

Tags: flexbox, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have an image in each `li` label with some text below each image. The parent `ul` and child `li` have flexbox properties as below.

Parent Ul:

```
{ display: flex; flex-wrap: row wrap; height: auto;}
```

Child Li:

```
ul.uploaded-pics li { flex: 0 1 auto; margin: 4px; align-self: center; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; }
ul.uploaded-pics label img { align-self: center; width: 100%; transition-duration: 0.2s; transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
```

I have used `align-self: center;` to get the images to align to the centre of the parent `ul`. However, the image sizes are not consistent and change according to the amount of text in each respective label. Where the label text flows into a 2nd ord 3rd line, the image above stretches to fill the blank space above. `align-self: flex-start;` and `align-self: flex-end;` also don't help and the image size differs in each `li`.

How do I get to fix the image sizes across `li` irrespective of the text in the `label` below, such that the images align with each other and the text labels also align themselves?

Find below working code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
ul.uploaded-pics { margin: 0; padding: 1px; border: 1px solid #aaa; border-radius: 4px}
ul.uploaded-pics { list-style-type: none;}
ul.uploaded-pics img { border: 2px;}
ul.uploaded-pics input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none;}
ul.uploaded-pics label { padding: 4px; display: block; position: relative; cursor: pointer; text-align: center; color: blue;}
ul.uploaded-pics label img { align-self: center; width: 100%; transition-duration: 0.2s; transform-origin: 50% 50%;}
ul.uploaded-pics { display: flex; flex-wrap: row wrap; height: auto;}
ul.uploaded-pics li { flex: 0 1 auto; margin: 4px; align-self: center; vertical-align: middle; border-radius: 2px; }
.pull-right .btn { margin-left: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id=Destination>Select the brands:
    <ul class="uploaded-pics">
        <li id=SubBrands>
            <input class="SubBrandCheckBox" name="Brand1" type="checkbox"/>
            <label><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPt4SyVUEAIX4GZ.jpg" />Brand1</label>
        </li>
        <li id=SubBrands>
            <input class="SubBrandCheckBox" name="Brand2" type="checkbox"/>
            <label><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPt4SybU8AAv8dm.jpg" />Brand2</label>
        </li>
        <li id=SubBrands>
            <input class="SubBrandCheckBox" name="Brand3" type="checkbox"/>
            <label><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPt4SyVUEAIX4GZ.jpg" />XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX Brand3</label>
        </li>
        <li id=SubBrands>
            <input class="SubBrandCheckBox" name="Brand4" type="checkbox"/>
            <label><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPt4SybU8AAv8dm.jpg" />XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX Brand4</label>
        </li>
        <li id=SubBrands>
            <input class="SubBrandCheckBox" name="Brand5" type="checkbox"/>
            <label><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPt4SyVUEAIX4GZ.jpg" />Brand5</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `align-self` and `flex-basis` to the `ul.uploaded-pics li` as follows:

```
ul.uploaded-pics li {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

then each of columns is the same size and images fit into it. You can remove both the `flex` property from `li` and the `flex-grow` property from `ul` because they are unnecessary.